# DebugAdapter bin folder not found on path "....vscode/extensions/ms-vscode.csharp-0.3.7/coreclr-debug/debugAdapters/OpenDebugAD7.exe."

Tags: c#, visual-studio-debugging, visual-studio-code

OS: Windows 10
dotnet-cli:
 Version:     1.0.0-beta-001598
 Commit Sha:  7582649f88

This is after following the instructions [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2016/03/10/experimental-net-core-debugging-in-vs-code/) for C# debugging.  Does it work yet for windows?

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message, it looks like you did not install the C# extension as per the instructions https://microsoft.gallery.vsassets.io/items?itemName=ms-vscode.csharp

Open your command pallet and verify that the correct version is installed. Or, if it is, remove it and try installing again

Comment: Totally installed. Multiple times.

Comment: I hit this problem too, and found that the .vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.csharp-0.3.7\coreclr-debug folder contained only 3 files, `dummy.cs`, `NuGet.config`, and `project.json`.

Comment: Did you run the .NET core installer as well?

Comment: the update was that I left the project.  I'm now doing development in java.

I miss C#...